# I wish *you* every day filled with/ I wish *your* every day

Tags: word-usage, pronouns, possessives

Any idea which one is correct:

> I wish you every day to be filled with lots of love.
>   I wish your every day to be filled with lots of love.

Comment: Your first version has an echo that *every day* refers to the wishing, while the second has *every day* referring to the filling.  Not much difference between them, though. If this is for Valentine's, just send chocolate.

Comment: Both are technically correct, but the first one feels choppy to be

Comment: No one would say: I wish you every day. That is wrong: I hope every one of your days is filled with lots of love. I wish every one of  your days were filled with lots of love. I wish you lots of love. Otherwise,the verbs have to be fixed. I wish you were rich. I wish + direct object + to be [past participle] is not grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

The first version (as a native BE speaker) may be grammatically okay but it's clumsy / not obvious how it should be read (i.e. do you wish it every day or do you wish once that they should be filled with love for ever and ever). It's not one that you would expect a native BE speaker to use.

The second version is grammatically okay and is the form that you'd be most likely to find. Of course you'd most likely find it inside a greetings card...

Answer (score 0):

As deadrat's [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/117573/i-wish-you-every-day-filled-with-i-wish-your-every-day#comment237457_117573) notes, both are grammatically correct.

> I wish you every day to be filled with lots of love.

In the first version, the wish is that *your correspondent be filled with lots of love*. You don't say how long you wish that filling to last, but you claim to do the wishing at least once a day, every day.

Structurally, the sentence is similar to the following:

- She comes here *every evening* to smell the flowers.

> I wish your every day to be filled with lots of love.

In the second version, the wish is that *your correspondent's every day be filled with lots of love*. This wish is made only once, with the hope that it is effective for all time.

Comment: Both are not grammatically correct at all.

Comment: @Lambie I've added an example that may help. Can you explain why you consider both of the OP's sentences ungrammatical?

Comment: I could if I weren't so lazy.  I wish  takes an indirect object; I wish ***you*** much luck. OR: I wish your days ***were filled with***. whatever. Think about it. While I try to formalize it. But not: I wish ***you*** your days. I'll come back, busy editing now.

Answer (score 0):

"Wish" can be used as a ditransitve verb and had it been used as such the desired wellwishing would then be viewed as spontaneous overflow of heartfelt emotion. None of our examples makes use of "wish" in the like manner.

In the first example 'you'  is the object and the rest is an adverbial pharase. The intended meaning is cumbersome and strained. Removing the object to the tail end with 'for you' can get the meaning free flowing without stumbling at  each word added after ' everyday'. The problem with the first example is that we were expecting a direct object where 'everyday' strikes a discordant note,  making us disillusioned and distracted at every step. All the comments and answers are a pointer to that direction.

The second example is, in that respect straight forward with a direct object. Every day is a noun here and other words there are intertwined as an epithet more in the nature of salutary tagline.

Both are correct. However, I would go with the second as it creates a sense of ebbing out of my heart.